# Change DefaultValue of DependencyProperty in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have created a UserControl which inherits from another Control. I search now a way, to change the defaultvalue of a DependencyProperty of the BaseControl. In WPF I can with OverrideMetadata override the DefaultValue of a DependecyProperty. But OverrideMetadata is not available in Silverlight.

Can someone give me a hint, how I can change a DefaultValue of a DependencyProperty in Silverlight?

Answer (score -1):

```
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(MyClass), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
        public string Text
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }
```

On this part you are setting the default value :

```
new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
```

it will be always initiated with an empty string.

EDIT:

Well, i really want to solve this one. I thought in a solution, doesn't seems to be the most correct one by we can try to improve together.
Do this in you base class:

```
    public virtual void DefineDefaultValue(object default)
    {
        defaultValue = default;
                    OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty");
    }

    static object defaultValue;
    public static object Define()
    {
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public int MyProperty
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(int), typeof(MainMenuBase), new PropertyMetadata((int)Define()));
```

After all, do this in your class constructor:

```
        public void ClassConstructor()
    {
        DefineDefaultValue("BlaBlaBla");
    }

    public override void DefineDefaultValue(object default)
    {
        base.DefineDefaultValue(default);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in my case my control inherits from another control which has for example already a TextProperty with DefaultValue string.Empty. I want now in my control only change the DefaultValue for example to "blabla". Not create a new Property!

Comment: Oh i'm sorry. I've looked for the answer but did not found. Just set the local value will not help you, will it?

Comment: mmhh - good idea, but I cannot change the DependencyProperty 'MyProperty' because I have no access to the BaseClass where I inherit from. So I am not able to change the Logik for getting the DefaultValue in the PropertyMetaData.

Comment: So what about implement singleton in your base class? It`s a kind of static instance of a class. This way you could access it`s properties by calling MyClass.Instance.

Comment: I have no access to change my baseclass.

Comment: I have the same problem. Any other ideas?